# Method that contains linq not working inside another linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity, entity-framework-6

I am currently being bothered by calling a method inside a linq whic is merely like this:

```
var entity=GetCustomers(false).Where(a => GetListCompcd(userlinkcd, rolecd).Any(b => b == a.comp_cd));
```

the GetListCompcd method:

```
private List<string> GetListCompcd(string userlinkcd, string rolecd)
    {
        List<string> listcompcd = new List<string>();
        if (rolecd == GeneralConst.L_ROLE_AGENT_CD)
        {
            listcompcd.Union(_unitOfWork.Repository<CONTACT>().Query().Filter(a => a.agent_cd == userlinkcd).Get().Select(a => a.comp_cd).ToList());
            listcompcd.Union(_unitOfWork.Repository<AGENT_2D>().Query().Filter(a => a.agent_cd == userlinkcd).Get().Select(a => a.comp_cd).ToList());
        }
        else if (rolecd == GeneralConst.L_ROLE_CGROUP_CD)
        { listcompcd.AddRange(_unitOfWork.Repository<CONTACT>().Query().Filter(a => a.agent_cd == userlinkcd).Get().Select(a => a.comp_cd).ToList()); }
        return listcompcd;
    }
```

this code has a error saying

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] GetListCompcd(System.String, System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

Answer (score -1):

This should do the trick:

```
var entity=GetCustomers(false).Where(a => GetListCompcd(userlinkcd, rolecd).Contains(a.comp_cd));
```

Comment: This will result in the exact same error for the exact same reason.

Comment: Yes, my previous answer was wrong, this edited answer should do the trick now.

Comment: It will never work when called in the context of an EF query.  EF doesn't know what to do with that method, as the error message in the OP states.  This is not a linq to objects query.